# Append Directory to UNC Path

Tags: powershell

I need to append a directory to a unc path, i need the following

```
\\APP401\I\Run\Folder\Client\20171031\25490175\Data\brtbvsch\
```

To look like

```
\\10.0.0.1\share\APP401\I\Run\Folder\Client\20171031\25490175\Data\brtbvsch\
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to add a string after the first \\ in the UNC path.

Comment: I was here with it , it had the \\\ in the path                                                                  
Join-Path -ChildPath $path -Path $pathn
10.0.0.1\share\\APP401\I\Run\Folder\Client\20171031\25490175\Data\brtbvsch\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex replace to accomplish this:

```
"\\APP401\I\Run\Folder\Client\20171031\25490175\Data\brtbvsch\" -replace "^\\",'\\10.0.0.1\share'
```

You could also use Join-Path as Olaf has suggested:

```
Join-Path -path "\\10.0.0.1\share" -ChildPath "\\APP401\I\Run\Folder\Client\20171031\25490175\Data\brtbvsch\".TrimStart('\')
```

Both of the above solutions work if your child path is in a variable as well:

```
$Path = "\\APP401\I\Run\Folder\Client\20171031\25490175\Data\brtbvsch\"
$Path -replace "^\\",'\\10.0.0.1\share'
```

Or:

```
Join-Path -Path "\\10.0.0.1\share" -ChildPath $Path.TrimStart('\')
```

Answer (score 0):

A **pragmatic solution** is to do **simple string concatenation**, given that **duplication of `\` in paths is benign** (multiple `\` are treated as a single `\`; try `Get-ChildItem C:\\Windows`, for instance).

```
$uncShare = '\10.0.0.1\share'
$path = '\\APP401\I\Run\Folder\Client\20171031\25490175\Data\brtbvsch'

# Works fine.
"${uncShare}${path}"

# Ditto
Join-Path $uncShare $path
```